# how to build a select function which have same rows count as in unnest array count

Tags: postgresql

Here i'm having a select statement:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(col1, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSUS'),
       col2,
       col3
FROM UNNEST(array['20211222110104765123', '20211222110104765123']) AS col1,
     UNNEST(array['name1', 'name2']) AS col2,
     UNNEST(array['ver1', 'ver2']) AS col3
```

I'm expecting a following output

```
2021-12-22 11:01:04.765123 +00:00, name1, ver1
2022-12-22 11:01:04.765123 +00:00, name2, ver2
```

But instead

```
2021-12-22 11:01:04.765123 +00:00,name1,ver1
2021-12-22 11:01:04.765123 +00:00,name2,ver1
2022-12-22 11:01:04.765123 +00:00,name1,ver1
2022-12-22 11:01:04.765123 +00:00,name2,ver1
2021-12-22 11:01:04.765123 +00:00,name1,ver2
2021-12-22 11:01:04.765123 +00:00,name2,ver2
2022-12-22 11:01:04.765123 +00:00,name1,ver2
2022-12-22 11:01:04.765123 +00:00,name2,ver2
```

Does anybody faced with the following issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass all three arrays to a single call to the unnest function

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(t.col1, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSUS'),
       t.col2,
       t.col3
FROM UNNEST(array['20211222110104765123', '20211222110104765123'], 
            array['name1', 'name2'], 
            array['ver1', 'ver2']) AS t(col1,col2,col3)
```